# How much does quantum uncertainty contribute to the uncertainty of earthquakes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, stability, critical-phenomena, earthquake, collective-excitations

More abstractly, the topic is: amplification of quantum uncertainty within dynamically unstable systems.

I'd like to have a calculable toy model, e.g. maybe a quantum version of the famous "abelian sandpile model". We would start in a pure state in which the "grains of sand" each have an equal and uncorrelated uncertainty in position, and then we try to understand the probability distribution over large avalanches.

But other ideas which capture something of the topic are also welcome!

Comment: @mmesser314 That refers to the amplification of a single quantum event by a measurement process. I am talking about the consequences of quantum uncertainty for the collective behavior of a large number of coupled entities. In a strictly deterministic system, definite initial conditions lead to definite outcomes, even if deterministic chaos is involved. If you have quantum uncertainty, does the wavefunction end up peaked around a single "classical earthquake", or is the phase volume smeared across many possible earthquakes? This is the kind of question I want to answer quantitatively.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the probability of an earthquake can be tied through calculation to events occurring on the quantum level; here is why.

The quantum realm is fully manifest at the length scale of atomic nuclei. The energies associated with those length scales are of order ~gamma rays. This means that to "communicate" with the nucleus requires us to use gamma rays or particles with ~gamma ray energies.

Now we jump up to the characteristic scale length of *earthquakes* which involve strain energy stored over ~thousands of cubic kilometers of rock and ask ourselves, how strongly are gamma rays coupled to strain fields on those length scales? The answer is, not strongly- if at all.

For the coupling to be strong requires that the strain fields in deformed rock possess some mechanism by which they can either generate gamma rays or respond to gamma irradiation. But what's really happening with strained rock is tensile and compressive stresses applied to the interatomic forces between adjacent atoms, and shear stresses applied to covalent (and directional) bonds between atoms. The energies involved are of order ~tens of eV.

This means you cannot "talk" to the quantum realm with mechanical stresses acting on the outermost electrons of a solid consisting of ~cubic kilometers of atoms and molecules.

Comment: How much do gamma rays coupled to something the size of a SQUID (the superconducting qubit, not the animal)? Not strongly. And therefore quantum uncertainty cannot have any influence on... quantum computers. (they are driven by microwaves, not gamma rays). I don't disagree with your conclusion, but I think your answer perpetuates myths about QM. But there is no length scale inherent in quantum mechanics. In atom interferometers atoms are separated by meters, then brought together and still form an interference pattern.

Comment: @Axensen No scale length characteristic of quantum effects? let me think about that. Do you live in Berkeley?

Comment: Yes I recently returned to Berkeley. Why? $\hbar$ is the constant that sets the scale of quantum effects. It has the units of action. If you want a length scale, you have to combine with a bunch of other unitful quantities, like $a_0=4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2/e^2m_e$. We get a more specific statement... the Bohr radius is not the length scale of quantum mechanics, it's the length scale of quantum mechanical behavior for a an electron orbiting a proton. Electrons orbiting a proton from much greater distances can be well approximated classically.

Comment: My daughter lives in Berkeley. I wound up going to UC Davis instead of Cal. Can you recommend a resource on the general topic of length and time scales that I can read to learn more? -NN

Comment: Sorry this is just information from my head. I don't have any resources I can link you to. Most of my best quantum knowledge comes from Prof. Robert Littlejohn's graduate level QM course at UC Berkeley (speaking of Berkeley). But that's a very unspecific recommendation. 
https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/1819/221.html

Comment: @AXensen OK, thanks.